# validate a string with numbers and arithmetic sign in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to validate text from a text field using JavaScript.

The text field I want to validate must contain only numbers and/or arithmetic signs (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`).

For example, the following string must be validated:

```
10 + 5 %
```

or

```
2 %
```

or simply

```
5
```

Which is the best way to validate these fields?

Comment: Nice. How far did you get in your try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
if (/^[ \d+*/%-]*$/.test(yourStringHere) {
   // is valid
}
```

Your examples also include spaces, so I've allowed for that in the regex - if you didn't really want spaces (as per your description) you'd remove the space inside the square brackets: `/^[\d+*/%-]*$/`

There is plenty of information about regular expressions [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [other places on the net](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression: `/^[\d\s+\-*/%]*$/`. Then you can use it to test your input:

```
var r = /^[\d\s+\-*/%]*$/;
console.log(r.test("10 + 5 %") ? "ok" : "bad"); // "ok"
console.log(r.test("10 + 5x %") ? "ok" : "bad"); // "bad"
```